# Desktop in Mobile User Agent: Firefox display improperly

Tags: firefox, user-agent

[image]

I use the same user agent string 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.17.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.2 Mobile/8H7 Safari/6533.18.5'
for FireFox and Chrome in desktop to see mobile versions of websites. But they displays in a huge different way.

Is FireFox unable to display a mobile version? I tried many sites and I think there should be something wrong with the browser.

How can I fix it? or I have to swith to Chrome to develop now.

Comment: This looks like a Facebook issue, how is it related to development? Why would you fake an iPhone in a desktop browser and expect a working result? I don't understand.

Comment: @Pekka웃, Ah...I like to see their mobile websites' page layout, css etc.. This would be impossible if I do this in FireFox.

Comment: A style sheet may not be gettign loaded - check out the "Net" tab in Firebug to see if anything goes wrong